# Executing two asynchronous tasks and updating AsyncTask message

Tags: android, android-asynctask, progressdialog, ui-thread

I have a piece of code which connects to a server and then logs in. While these two tasks (*connect to server* and *login*) are being executed, a progress dialog appears.

```
final ProgressDialog pd = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
pd.setIndeterminate(true);
pd.setCancelable(false);

// While connecting to the server, the dialog should say the following:
pd.setTitle("Connecting...");
pd.setMessage("Connecting to " + hostname + "...");

pd.show();

new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        try {

            // First task is executed. Progress dialog should say "Connecting..."
            executeTask1();

            // When the first task (connecting to server) is ready, I want the title
            // and the message of the progress dialog to be changed into this:
            pd.setTitle("Logging in"); //// MARKED LINE, see below. ////
            pd.setMessage("Trying to log in to server...");

            // Second task is executed.
            executeTask2();

            // Shows a screen and dismisses the ProgressDialog.
            showScreen(ScreenConstant.LIST_RESIDENTS);
            pd.dismiss();
        }
        catch (Exception exc) { }
    }
}
```

But I ran into two problems:

1. A `RuntimeException` is raised when the MARKED LINE (see above) is executed: "Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views"
2. The login task gets a response from the server, but this response is asynchronous.

I want a `ProgressDialog` to appear with the text "Connecting..." while the connection attempt is being executed. After the connection is successful, I want the text of the progress dialog to be changed into "Logging in...", while the login attempt is being performed.

Now how should I achieve this?

#### EDIT

Notice that `executeTask2()` triggers a task to be run in a **different** thread; it sends a login request to the server, therefore I need to wait until that thread signals me when it's ready.

Answer (score 0):

Any code that touches the UI should be done on the Main Thread, so you'll need to use `onProgressUpdate()` and `publishProgress()` to facilitate this.

eg:

```
public void onProgressUpdate(Void... progress){
    super.onProgressUpdate(progress);
    pd.setTitle("Logging in");
    pd.setMessage("Trying to log in to server..."):
}
```

and in your `doInBackground()` method:

```
executeTask1();
//task one finished, update UI
publishProgress();
```

In addition to this, you should dismiss your `ProgressDialog` in `onPostExecute()`, as this is also executed on the Main Thread

Comment: Thanks for this answer. However, this would only solve problem #1 as described in my question. But how can I pause the execution of the thread, to wait for the server response to my login request? (Do I need `Thread.join()` perhaps?)

Comment: why not move the code from the second Tasks doInBackground() into the first tasks doInBackground()? it seems a waste to use two different AsyncTasks for this

Comment: What do you mean? I do not use two different `AsyncTask`s, see question.

Comment: you're using a different thread for executeTask2(), why? you already have a background thread when executing in doInBackground(), why do you need another?

Comment: so dismiss your ProgressDialog in the success/failure callback of the library async task

Answer (score 0):

You need to run the progress dialog in the main thread, only the thread that create the view can update or call it thus giving you that exception.

**sample:**

```
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        try {

            // First task is executed. Progress dialog should say "Connecting..."
            executeTask1();

            // When the first task (connecting to server) is ready, I want the title
            // and the message of the progress dialog to be changed into this:
            getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    pd.setTitle("Logging in"); //// MARKED LINE, see below. ////
                    pd.setMessage("Trying to log in to server...");
                }
            });


            // Second task is executed.
            executeTask2();

            // Shows a screen and dismisses the ProgressDialog.
            showScreen(ScreenConstant.LIST_RESIDENTS);

            getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                 pd.dismiss();  


                }
            });

        }
        catch (Exception exc) { }
    }
```

**note:**

It would be wise to dismiss the dialog in the `post execute` method of the `Asynctask` that it run in the main thread.

Comment: Thanks. But this would only solve problem #1 as described in my question; problem #2 remains unsolved. (See comment below @panini's answer.)